# 404 Not Found on CSS file even though it's in the correct directory

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

This is in the template file:

```
function add_pt_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style ('pt-style', ROOT_PATH.'/pt.css', array(), '1.0.0');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_pt_style' );

get_header();
```

Here are my files:

[image]

Here is the error:

[image]

I cannot figure out why it's not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think using ROOT_PATH is what you want to do here.  That loads the server root.

try this code:

```
//add some pizazz
function pt_load_plugin_css () {
    
    $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
    wp_enqueue_style ('pt-style', $plugin_url . 'css/pt.css', '1.0.0');
}
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pt_load_plugin_css');
```

Comment: plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) gives me the child theme directory because this is in a template file, which is in the child theme dir

Comment: But you are right, if I move the enqueue to my plugin file, it works fine. I guess there's some problem with trying to do it from the template file. Not sure if I should mark answered or not.

Comment: ah.  looking at your screenshot it looked like the whole project was a plugin.  If you want to go another route let me know!  let me know where the css (plugin?) and where the enqueue function is though!